# Determine running time of the code

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, asymptotic-complexity

I have written following dp code today, it worked fine as it got some points in for submission ([here is the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/)). However I am not able to determine the running time of my code. I feel like its `O(n^2 * log D)`  but I can't prove it.

```
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<string, bool> m;
    bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
        int n = s.length();
        string t = "";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            t += s.at(i);
            //cout << t << endl;
            if(wordDict.find(t) != wordDict.end()){
                m[t] = true;
                string x = "";
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                    x += s.at(j);
                }
                if(x == ""){
                    return true;
                }
                if(m.find(x) != m.end()){
                    if(m[x] == true){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(wordBreak(x, wordDict)){
                        m[x] = true;
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        //cout << x << endl;
                        m[x] = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //m[t] = false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Typically measuring this involves either instrumenting the code will counters to see how many times you do a certain thing in the code (iterations, comparisons, etc) with varying values of `N`, `D` etc, and plot the results in a graph of the result, or do the same but measure the time the execution takes with varying values of `N` and `D`. Also `O(x)` gives "the dominant `x`", so unless `log D` is very large,  and N is small, `N^2` will dominate, so the value is `O(N^2)`, even if there, tehchnically is a `* log D` involved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have `O(n*n)` complexity. You use memorisation and every step of your alrotithm produce at least 1 new value in `m`. There is `n*n/2` substrings in any string, so you will find solution for entire string with n*n/2 passages in worst case.

PS: consider unordered_map works with `O(1)`.

EDIT:

It might be more properly to consider unordered_map works with O(n) in your case. `m.find` will need to calculate hash for it's argument, wich is string. may be it will work faster if you store indexes instead of string itself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would rewrite is as follows (untested):

```
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<string, bool> m;
    bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) 
    {
        while (!s.empty())
        {
        int n = s.size() ;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            //cout << t << endl;
            if(wordDict.find(s.substr(0, i)) != wordDict.end()){
                m[t] = true;
                s = s.substr(i) ;
                break ;
        }
        return !m.empty();
    }
};
```

The basic idea is that once you find a match then you can remove the matching part from the string. Then I would say it's n * logD. After all you make just one pass on the for loop. Assuming you find a match at m < n then you get a new loop over (n-m).

Comment: `s.substr(0, i)` - this operation is `O(i)` and you do it for all `0 <= i < N`. So its `O(n^2)` in total.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it.

```
bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
    if (s.empty()) return true;

    vector<bool> dp(s.size(), false);
    for (int i = 0; i < dp.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            if (wordDict.find(s.substr(j, i - j + 1)) != wordDict.end() &&
                (j == 0 || dp[j - 1]))
            {
                dp[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return dp.back();
}
```